# Show title when I hover image connected to mysql using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, lightbox

I want to show the image title when hovered to the image connected to mysql using php.

Here are the code I used.

```
<div class="galleryko">
<?php $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_gallery_featured")?>

    <div class="lalagyan1">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)):?>
        <div class="lalagyan">
            <div id="wew">
                <a href="admin/featured/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" rel="lightbox[plants]"><img src="admin/featured/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" style="width:150px; height: 150px;"/></a></br>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile?>  
    </div>   
</div>
```

Then I tried to insert a TITLE inside the code of

```
<a href="admin/featured/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" rel="lightbox[plants]" title="SOMETEXT"><img src="admin/featured/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" style="width:150px; height: 150px;"/></a></br>
```

But when I hover the images after I did, what happened was, all images are entitled with SOMETEXT, Now I want to show the TITLE of an IMAGE seperately.

Some one please solve my problem,. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: well, that it says "SOMETEXT" is pretty straight forward... you hardly coded it into the title= tag. Just use a database column (if existing) for that aswell (and use alt/title correctly)

Comment: How can i put some title? where do i insert those titles in the images, Ive already put the code alt=$row['title']" but nothings happend, no title or sometext when i hoverd the image or clicked the image.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: what do you mean by: You want to show the TITLE of an IMAGE seperately?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `title="SOMETEXT"` and add something like this to `img` tag `alt="$row['title']"`

Comment: How can i put some title? where do i insert those titles in the images, Ive already put the code alt=$row['title']" but nothings happend, no title or sometext when i hoverd the image or clicked the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="admin/featured/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" rel="lightbox[plants]" title="<?php echo $row['title']?>"><img src="admin/featured/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" style="width:150px; height: 150px;"/></a>
```